# Angular 2 : How to keep two methods from repeating

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I implement my `if/else` statement only once so that I don't repeat this fragment of code in my header component as shown below:

```
export class HeaderMainComponent {
logoAlt = 'We Craft beautiful websites'; // Logo alt and title texts

@ViewChild('navTrigger') navTrigger: ElementRef;

isMenuShown: false;

constructor(private layoutService: LayoutService, private renderer: Renderer) { }

menuToggle(event: any) {
    if (this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.contains('opened')) {
        this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.remove('opened');
    } else {
        this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.add('opened');
    }
}

onMenuSelect(event: any) {
    this.isMenuShown = false;

    if (this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.contains('opened')) {
        this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.remove('opened');
    } else {
        this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.add('opened');
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just call menuToggle from your onMenuSelect after this.isMenuShown = false; statment?

Comment: Why not using template binding (`ngClass`) instead o_O ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

souldn't you just do this?

```
export class HeaderMainComponent {
logoAlt = 'We Craft beautiful websites'; // Logo alt and title texts

@ViewChild('navTrigger') navTrigger: ElementRef;

isMenuShown: false;

constructor(private layoutService: LayoutService, private renderer: Renderer) { }

menuToggle(event: any) {
    if (this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.contains('opened')) {
        this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.remove('opened');
    } else {
        this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.add('opened');
    }
}

onMenuSelect(event: any) {
    this.isMenuShown = false;

    this.menuToggle(event); // Must apply the event binding as well
}

}
```

Comment: Typescript is putting out an error `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

Comment: Problem fixed, we need to bind the event as well - `this.menuToggle(event);`. Please someone tell me if this is the correct way to say this.